# Lambda Calculus Free Variable Issue

Tags: lambda-calculus

I found Mike Gordon's *Introduction to Functional Programming* [Notes](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mjcg/Teaching/FuncProg/Notes/Notes.ps.gz)  on the web and I'm trying to work through it. On page 9 there's this question:

```
Find an example to show that if V1 = V2 , then even if V2 is not free in E1,
it is not necessarily the case that:

(λ V1 V2 . E ) E1 E2 = E [E1/V1][E2/V2]
```

I'm guessing that I could say that since V1 and V2 are equal, we could redo it thus:

```
(λ V2 V1 . E ) E1 E2
```

and therefore say

```
(λ V1 . E[E1/V2] ) E2
```

given the stipulation that V2 is not free in E1. But then we cannot say

```
E[E1/V2][E2/V1]
```

because E2 would necessarily have V1 free. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a counterexample. Apart from that, I don't understand your reasoning in the last step – why does V1 have to occur freely in E2? Apart form that, this `E[E1/V2][E2/V1]` in your last step is not a statement. What do you mean by saing "We cannot say that `E[E1/V2][E2/V1]`?"

You should try to construct an *explicit* counterexample for this hypothesis, i.e. choose `V1=V2=x` (it really doesn't matter, due to α conversion) and then find *explicit* expressions `E`, `E1`, `E2` such that they fulfil the assumption of the hypothesis (`V2` not free in `E1`), but the expression `` `E[E1/V2][E2/V2] `` is not equal to the reduct of `(λV1 V2. E ) E1 E2`.

Since you said you wanted to do this by yourself, I will not give you the solution, but feel free to ask for more pointers.

Comment: It seems that saying `(λ v1 v2 . E) E1 E2 = E [E1/V1][E2/V2]` where `v1` and `v2` are different is like saying for example `λv1 . (λ v2 . v1) E1 E2` which could be betaed down to `(λ v2 . E1) E2` which would be just `E1.` But if we're trying to say the original redex with `v1 = v2` or just `v`, using our example: `λv . (λ v . v) E1 E2` which would beta to `E2`, which is a contradiction. Therefore, (and in general) you can't alpha `λ v1 v2 . E` to `λ v v . E`.